# GitHub master rejected

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I am using Eclipse and eGit for Githun stuff. I am NEW to GitHub so this may be easy for you... anyways...

I am trying to push to my repository over at https://github.com/UrbanTwitch and as you can see I have done the tutorial...

Comment: I've found it a bit easier to debug eGit repository problems from the Git Repository Explorer.  (Window -> Perspectives -> Other -> Git ...).  Click the 'clone repository' there just to see if you can get connected.  The error messages seem better when there are problems.

Comment: @P.T. I will try that and report back.. thanks it also says my environment variable HOME is not set...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That usually means that you have never created an SSH connection to a given server before. If you accept, it should store the server's key and not come up again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a page to resolve GIT ssh issue: http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

You'll also need to generate a key and then register to your account in github.com.